# Upshot/Knockout Architectural Best Practices - What is the preferred provider to use in communicating between Upshot and .NET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api, breeze, upshot

For a current project, I am trying to get a feel for how to effectively utilize Knockout 2.1.0, Upshot 1.0.0.2, ASP.NET MVC4, and Entity Framework 4.3. There are a lot of basic architectural questions which don't seem to have ready answers. I am enumerating several of my questions (in separate posts) in the hopes that someone can provide reasonable guidance for myself and others as we attempt to implement this combination in real-world applications.

In **Steve Sanderson's** awesome presentation on Knockout and Upshot.js at TechDays Netherlands in February, he mentioned Upshot can accommodate multiple methods of connecting to a server. (If you have not seen the presentation, it is well worth a watch. You can view it at http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/Techdays-2012-the-Netherlands/2159.)

Unfortunately, he did not have time to detail what those communications mechanisms are or which was recommended and in what circumstances.

According to **Denver Developer** in his blog post titled “Digging into 
Upshot.js” (http://denverdeveloper.wordpress.com/2012/03/07/digging-into-upshot-js/), there are three data providers exposed by Upshot.js. 
These are:

•        the default is **DataProvider()** and uses the /Submit method and the  operation you provide it to get data using jQuery’s $.ajax method. (AG Note: I believe this generally connects with **DbDataController** objects exposed by **WebAPI** but am unsure of precisely what the limitations are.)

•        the next is **riaDataProvider()** – similar to the first, but it uses  the /json/SubmitChanges method and /json/{your opertion} to get data

•        finally we also have **odataDataProvider()** – this one is quite  different because it does not currently support updating data – it is  read-only.

A number of closely related questions naturally present themselves regarding the selection of a provider for typical use.

- Which data provider is better—the default data provider or the RIA    data provider?
- Which one is recommended for normal use and under what circumstances?
- What are the performance implications of using the normal **DataProvider** vs the **riaDataProvider**?

On a related note, there appears to be very little documentation on upshot on the Internet. Other than drudging through the 4700+ lines of code in upshot.js, are there any other decent sources of documentation for this library?

The resources I have looked at so far include the following (plus a few more).

- Source code from Steve Sanderson's SPA demo (available from http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2012/03/06/single-page-application-packages-and-samples/).
- Source code from Bart Jolling's variations on Steve Sanderson's SPA demo application from his article on "Building Single Page Applications with ASP.NET MVC4" (parts 1-4). http://bartjolling.blogspot.com/2012/04/building-single-page-apps-with-aspnet.html
- Big Shelf SPA demo code from ASP.NET site - http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/spa-samples/sample-bigshelf-application
- Microsoft ASP.NET "A Tour through SPA" (basically focuses on upshot samples)
  http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/spa-samples.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should avoid using upshot and use http://www.breezejs.com/ instead

ASP.Net MVC Roadmap (note that upshot is not being developed further):
http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Roadmap

keep an eye on the road map plus john Papa's blog (http://www.johnpapa.net/building-single-page-apps-with-knockout-jquery-and-web-api-ndash-the-story-begins) - that should keep
you on the right path

update : i just started playing around with hot towel - it roles Breeze, Durandal.js Knockout.js and Twitter Bootstrap (among others)
into a very nice template  ...its looking pretty cool so far

https://github.com/johnpapa/HotTowel

Comment: Thanks for the tip on HotTowel, looks very interesting.

Answer (score -1):

Which provider to use depends on your server-side dataService type. In my practice they are:

1. WCF RIA service + upshot (with riaDataProvider) + knockout.
2. ASP.NET WEB API + upshot (with dataProvider) + knockout. (both will do good job for you!)
3. WCF data Service + upshot (with oDataProvider) + knockout. (read data only now) 
   For oData server side service, "JayData" is a good option

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I believe it simply summarized the information I provided in my question.